# Animation within headerView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently trying to add an animation to the user's xp bar.

If I had the animation in the collectionViewController, the animation is well loaded (once). However, if I had the animation within the headerView (because I would like to add the bar on the profile picture) the bar is launched more than one time:

[image]

This is my code (headerViewCell):

```
let shapeLayerXp = CAShapeLayer()

override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      showUserXp()
      self.animateXp(toValue: 1)
}

func showUserXp() {
      let center = profileImage.center
      let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 40, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
      shapeLayerXp.path = circularPath.cgPath

      let color = UIColor(red: 122 / 255, green: 205 / 255, blue: 186 / 255, alpha: 1)

      shapeLayerXp.strokeColor = color.cgColor
      shapeLayerXp.lineWidth = 4
      shapeLayerXp.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
      shapeLayerXp.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

      shapeLayerXp.strokeEnd = 0

      self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayerXp)


}

func animateXp(toValue: Int) {
      let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
      basicAnimation.toValue = toValue
      basicAnimation.duration = 2

      basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
      basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

      shapeLayerXp.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
}
```

The headerViewCell is launched like that:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

      let headerViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! UserHeaderView

// ....

return cell

}
```

Comment: You are calling `showUserXp()` and `animateXp()` in `layoutSubViews()` so every time system decides to layout the header cell the animation will happen again.  Obviously that's happening when the collection view is scrolled but could also happen at other times e.g. device rotation, header cell re-use.  What are you trying to achieve?  Should it just animate when the controller is first shown and then only at certain other times?

Comment: I would like to animate the bar only when the viewController is launched (once)

Comment: Is there just a single header cell for this controller?  How is the cell defined (storyboard, xib file, manually)?

Comment: I edited my first post to show you how the cell is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right assuming there is only one header cell ever in the controller unless the data is changed (e.g. a different user) then you can set a property on the view controller to indicate if the animation has been shown.

Something like this would do:

```
var animatedHeader = false // Starts false because we want an animation the first time.
```

Then when obtaining the header cell for the first time you can decide to fire the animation or not like this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

      let headerViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! UserHeaderView

      if !self.animatedHeader {
          cell.showUserXp()
          cell.animateXp()

          self.animatedHeader = true
      }

      return cell
}
```

The `showUserXp()` and `animateXp()` methods will need to be public of course.

Using this method the header cell will only animate the first time it is dequeued and therefore displayed.

If you did want to animate it again you just need to reset the `animateHeader` property and reload the collection view (or just the header).

If there is more than one header then you will need to keep track of each of them separately.

**Edit:** This does require (accidentally) the same cell to be used because of how the showXP and animateXP functions are defined.  If I was doing this myself I would probably use something more like this approach:

```
func showUserXp(animated: Bool) {
    let center = profileImage.center
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 40, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    shapeLayerXp.path = circularPath.cgPath

    let color = UIColor(red: 122 / 255, green: 205 / 255, blue: 186 / 255, alpha: 1)

    shapeLayerXp.strokeColor = color.cgColor
    shapeLayerXp.lineWidth = 4
    shapeLayerXp.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayerXp.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    shapeLayerXp.strokeEnd = 0

    self.contentView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayerXp)

    if animated {
        let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        basicAnimation.toValue = toValue
        basicAnimation.duration = 2

        basicAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        shapeLayerXp.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "urSoBasic")
    } else {
        shapeLayerXp.strokeEnd = 1
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let headerViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! UserHeaderView

    if self.animatedHeader {
        cell.showUserXp(animated: false)
    } else {
        cell.showUserXp(animated: true)

        self.animatedHeader = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

So now you can show the header cell using an animation or not and whether you do use the animation is controlled by the animatedHeader property.  This now no longer relies on a specific cell being dequeued.

Comment: i'd rather hold a pointer to the headerViewCell in the VC in this case. The collectionView is not obligated to return the same instance which each call. This relies on an implementation detail

Comment: Using my approach it's easy to expand out.  For example suppose you now have 500 items in the list you just keep an array of 50 bools controlling whether they have been presented to the user (therefore had the header animated).  If you keep a reference to the header cell you are now needing to keep references to 500 header cells and are now bypassing the whole idea of dequeuing which is done for performance and memory reasons.

Comment: your approch is flawed I fear. it only works if the collection view dequeues the right cell. so you rely on the collection view to not reuse a view. [deleted my post and downvoted]

Comment: You are partially correct because the cell starts with the user XP not shown (I didn't check that out completely).  I was just really using the example given to show how to animate only once.  If I was doing this for real I would have a function to set the XP value with an animated property.  Then for the first time it's seen I would show it animated and then every other time not animated.  That way you don't care what cell is used.  I will update my answer to show this more clearly.